# How to get meaningful words by splitting a continuous string?

Tags: python, string, split

Well I am trying to parse a particular html response.I have successfully extracted the text from the page in a form of continuous string.

for eg:

> The Dormouse's storyThe Dormouse's storyOnce upon a time there were three little sisters  and their names wereElsie LacieandTillie \nand they lived at the bottom of a well
>   Blockquote

My 1st Question is I need to split the string to get individual words like
eg:

> storyOnce

should be converted to a list of meaningful words...

> [The,....,story,Once,....]

and I also need to get rid of "\n" characters. I tried using

> .strip

but it doesn't seem to work. I thinks I may be using it in wrong way.
I am a newbie so please elaborate the answers.That will be helpful.

Comment: so you are trying to introduce a space? please edit your question to make a clear input example and the desired output. what you have is not very clear

Comment: It would be easy If you do it while extracting text.

Comment: @WannaBeCoder Cant be done!!!The text is exactly the way i extracted it.

Comment: I think it is a hard problem to be able to figure out the `storyOnce` should be `story` and `once` unless you use some NLP library. I think you are doing something wrong when extracting the tex. Are these from the same html response. Are they already attached?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without seeing the relevant portion of your code. How are you parsing the HTML? All we can say for certain without seeing your code is that you must be doing _something_ wrong because you shouldn't be getting those `\n` sequences in your output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For removing the `\n` chars strip will only work if they are at beginning and end of string.

You can use `split` instead and attach string back without the `\n` if you end up splitting on `\n`

For you initial problem since the text is exactly as you extracted it, what I would do is split on space first

```
string.split(' ')
```

which will give something like

```
[The, Dormouse's, storyThe, Dormouse's, storyOnce, upon, a, time,...]
```

and then you can use some simple dictionary mapping with a smart algorithm as follows:

Iterate over the resulting list:

- Use a dictionary or some NLP library to check for matches (e.g story matches 'storyThe' - so it should split - you can do another check that the rest 'The' exists in dictionary too'
- try to smartly ignore names which will not be in dictionary. Some NLP libraries can help with that.

This is a [text segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_segmentation) problem so you need to use some form of natural language processing to do some tokenization and text extraction.

@WannaBeCoder below suggests [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) platform and book here:
http://www.nltk.org/book/

Have fun this is challenging and cool!

Comment: You could probably add the text segmentation part too to make your answer more elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want [text segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_segmentation). From a old link I bookmarked [this](https://gist.github.com/miku/7279824) seems to do the task for you. You could also use [NLTK segmentation](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html).

Answer (score 1):

I am creating a similar program. I created a word list from sentence using .split(). And compared it to a dictionary. Then for unknown words. I used binary map and created all possible combinations of chunks. Then from those combinations I seperated unique chunks. And compared it to dictionary. Now I have all possible combination of unknown word and parts from the word which are from dictionary. I compared both for everypossible chunk combination of unknown word, so that I have least possible (number of chunks -  number of words in that chunk from dictionary).

But my method is time consuming. And has problems with ambiguous lines like 'loveisnowhere'.

Comment: I am curious how you dealt with ambiguous ones did you go with higher probability distribution or something fancy or just picked a random one that matched dictionary?

Comment: I still have to tackle that problem. Currently it gives me a list of all best possible output. And one of these output is the expected one. And for most sentence this list is less than 10 elements.

Comment: interesting, I suggest you could use some probability values. If you have a corpus that covers many sentences and wordings, it is easy to assign probabilities to how many times this phrase occurs given that it occurs after ...etc and choose the one with higher value

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
ans = ""
for a in re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*',"The Dormouse's storyThe Dormouse's storyOnce upon a time there were three little sisters and their names wereElsie LacieandTillie \nand they lived at the bottom of a well Blockquote"):
   ans+=a.strip()+' '

ans
"The Dormouse's story The Dormouse's story Once upon a time there were three little sisters and their names were Elsie Lacieand Tillie \nand they lived at the bottom of a well Blockquote "
```

Comment: this sounds like you are assuming that in all attached words you will have capital letter for the second one which might not be the case.

Comment: If the text was `The Dormouse's storythe Dormouse's storyonce upon a time there were three little sisters and their names wereElsie LacieandTillie \nand they lived at the bottom of a well Blockquote`    Your code fails